# how can I identify points are inside convex hull in Matlab separately

Tags: matlab, function, convex

I created 3D convex hull plot in Matlab. It seems in this function, some of laser points were used for facets of convex hull, but some other points are situated inside convex hull . My question is that how can I identify these points in Matlab separately. Which way is applicable for calculating the perpendicular distance of these points situated inside of convex hull to the nearest convex hull facet (distance from each point to the closest facet of the convex hull)? 
I would be very grateful if you could introduce me some references about convex hull function.

Answer (score 0):

On the Matlab file exchange, there is a great function called [inhull](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10226-inhull), which will test whether your points are inside the hull or not.  I'm not sure that it provides the distance from the points to the nearest facet, but perhaps the methods used in the code would be simple to change to provide this output.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the function, `tsearchn`.

The following code creates a sphere in 3D and computes the delaunay triangularization. We then set-up `testpoints` variable with points to test if they are inside the sphere or not. `t` returns indices back into `TRI` for tetrahedra facet that are closest to the point or NaN if the point is outside the sphere.

```
[X,Y,Z] = sphere(N);

TRI = delaunay(X(:),Y(:),Z(:));

testpoints = [0 0 0; 0 .5 0; 1 2 0]
t = tsearchn([X(:) Y(:) Z(:)],TRI,testpoints)

figure;
trisurf(TRI,X(:),Y(:),Z(:));
```

Output is,

```
t =

    8182
    7779
     NaN
```